# Word that means "more accepting of other cultures"?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

Is there a word that means "more accepting of other cultures" that has a tone appropriate for use as a mild counter to "xenophobic"? Essentially a mild opposite of "xenophobic".

Example: "This organization outwardly claims to want to be more _____, but its actions lately have shown an unsettling xenophobic trend."

Comment: Another possibility is the phrase 'culturally sensitive'.

Comment: For those who actually *like* other cultures (as opposed to simply being "less intolerant"), there's always OED's ***xenophil** adj. (also **xenophile**) fond of or attracted by foreign things or people; also as noun, such a person.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers I had considered that, although "xenophilic" had a more extreme connotation than I wanted.

Comment: @Jason: I would say you've already used one of the best words for the job in your question text. I'd like to think, for example, that Britain is on balance an *accepting* and *accommodating* society/nation, both in terms of accepting people *from* other cultures who arrive here, *and* in respect of other cultures *in other countries*. The former eventually become "British", whilst extending our shared culture. The latter, we help to live as *they* want (except if they "want" to live under the Taliban or other repressive regimes, obviously).

Comment: Funny, "accepting" didn't even occur to me. Brilliant!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**tolerant** would fit.

[1](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tolerant)

> willing to accept feelings, habits, or beliefs that are different from your own

[2](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/tolerant)

> An individual can be tolerant, and so can a community or a nation if it accepts people from lots of different cultures or backgrounds

Comment: @Jason: Be warned that in the UK at least, *multiculturalism* is increasingly seen as a ***failed*** attempt at "social engineering". In the 90s and the early part of this century it was "overpromoted" by central/local government, leading to resentment in certain areas where the incoming immigrant community were effectively being encouraged to become the locally dominant culture. There's more emphasis today on helping newcomers to be absorbed *into* the indigenous culture (with some degree of modification on both sides, obviously), rather than preserving "immigrant cultures abroad".

Comment: ...And the dictionaries don't seem to agree on the principal sense. AHD has merely (1) 'Of, relating to, or including several cultures.'.

Comment: @Jason: Well, this question is between the word choice for your sentence and the word fits to the definition. In my opinion, "tolerant" satisfies both. "multiculturalism" can be the character of the company but saying "more multicultural" does not seem very right to me. If you are multicultural, you are multicultural. To fit "more tolerant" in a sentence is a more common usage for these situations.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Oh; Thanks for the UK tip, that's a good one. Perhaps "inclusive" is better in that regard (although it's a little broad).

Comment: @ermanen That's a good point, I guess "multicultural" doesn't fit the example sentence that well.

Comment: (Although, one thing about "tolerant" vs. "inclusive" is that, to me, "inclusive" suggests actively including, while "tolerant" suggests *not* actively *excluding*. I'll have to think about it more to decide which of those is closer to what I really mean.)

Comment: @Edwin: I don't think there's anything *wrong* with that definition, but OED puts it more precisely: *Of or relating to a society consisting of a number of cultural groups, esp. in which the **distinctive cultural identity** of each group **is maintained**.* Not everyone has yet grasped exactly what's been happening (and more particularly, *why*) in the UK over the past  decade and more. But what it nets down to is that *British* culture has asserted itself; within reasonable accomodations, immigrants are now overtly expected (and welcomed) to become British, not to become a "culture within".

Comment: @FF No, it gives a different sense (or perhaps more accurately conflates what the AHD people identify as senses) here. AHD gives other sense/s after the one I mention, and Collins and other dictionaries have slightly different approaches. I'm _not_ saying that what you say **isn't** the principal usage in the UK nowadays though. I'd certainly avoid it here.

Answer (score 9):

**multicultural** is the current mainstream intellectual word for this.

Answer (score 9):

**Cosmopolitan** may suit your needs depending on the connotations you're after. It suggests an awareness of global culture and is also an antonym of *provincial* (in the “small minded” sense).

Comment: Oh, that's a good one too.

Comment: Long been used of cities in precisely this context

Answer (score 5):

I've heard the word 'inclusive' used to describe this kind of behavior in the corporate setting.

Comment: I like this alot; it's a good one to file away in case I have to use it in close proximity to (or as a less buzz-y alternative to) "multicultural" or "tolerant".

Answer (score 4):

I would say that the person would be **open-minded** or an **internationalist**.

Answer (score 3):

**Culturally competent**.

> Cultural competence is a set of congruent behaviors, attitudes, and
>   policies that come together in a system, agency or among professionals
>   and enable that system, agency or those professions to work
>   effectively in cross-cultural situations.
>   http://nccccurricula.info/culturalcompetence.html

Answer (score 2):

Such an organization or person is **pluralistic**,  or "culturally pluralistic" if you want to avoid any confusion with other meanings of pluralism (e.g. the political theory).

I nod approvingly in the direction of *multicultural*, which has all the trappings of a buzzword in current usage. However, I prefer pluralistic because it indicates not merely a tolerance of disparate cultures but a belief in their ability to coexist amicably without losing or sacrificing their unique identities.

Where multicultural is an obligation in modern society, pluralistic is an aspiration. Where multicultural signifies tolerance, pluralistic signifies integration without assimilation.

Consequently, I think it serves better as a counterpoint to xenophobia, without reaching as far as xenophile.

Answer (score -1):

Cultural Hospitality feels like it encompasses openness and eagerness.  I bet langauges other than English have just the right word!